# Normal desktop on vnc viewer

Tags: linux, ssh, vnc, vncviewer

I'm learning to use VNC viewer for remote connection to server.
VNC viewer is successfully connects to server, but here is how remote desktop looks like

[image]

I have already tried to uncomment two strings is `xstartap` file:

```
# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
unset SESSION_MANAGER
exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
```

and tried to use `kde`, but without any result.
Any ideas how to make normal desktop?

Comment: What distro and version is running on the remote server? what is your "normal desktop"? How exactly did you try to use kde, and what happened?

Comment: Back when I was a student, we used to walk uphill through the snow to get a desktop like that. Kids today.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a default xsession over vnc (the same one you would get if you would login on the host via the display-manager.

You can achieve this by installing `Xvnc` on the remote host. What this does is execute the X-server with a virtual display served over vnc. You'll see the display manager in your vnc session first when you connect to the remote host, and can login to your "normal desktop" (i.e. the one configured to be run by your display manager) from there.

HTH,

ppenguin